# Vue 2 Webpack 3 Bootstrap 4 scss customization

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4, webpack-3

In my vue 2 application, wanted to define media breakpoint like below

```
@include media-breakpoint-between(md, lg){
  body {
      background-color: red;
  }
}
```

and hence forth imported in the vue file bootstrap.scss
@import "~../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

But this above import failed error on npm run dev

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-6a244a7e","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":true}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=1&bustCache!./client/App.vue
Module build failed:
undefined
       ^
      Argument `$map2` of `map-merge($map1, $map2)` must be a map
```

Any suggestions to resolve this issue

Comment: I don't believe this is related to your issue, but your bootstrap import should be `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss;"`, as `~` will resolve the node_modules path.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue using Bootstrap 4 in conjunction with Material Design Icons. It turned out to be a variable name collision and was resolved by rearranging the import order.

If you provide additional error output and/or more source surrounding your bootstrap import I may be able to provide additional help.

Comment: this is my import:
$popover-arrow-outer-width: calc($popover-arrow-width + 1px) !default;
"@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';"
"@import '~mdbootstrap/scss/mdb.scss';"
"@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';"
"@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick';"
"@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme';"
"@import '~md-checkbox/sass/md-checkbox';"

Are any problems? I got the similar issue :(
Just ignore the ". I added it because I can't use @ charactor.